# Google app engine: ndb query made cleaner

Tags: google-app-engine

On Google App Engine, I would like to know if it is possible to construct the conditions in the ndb query in a way described as follows. Suppose I have the following code:

```
if bidded == '':
    productRanks = Product.query(Product.bidTime>=startDate,
                                 Product.bidTime<endDate).fetch()         
elif bidded == 'yes':
    productRanks = Product.query(Product.bidTime>=startDate
                                 Product.bidTime<endDate,
                                 Product.bidded=='yes').fetch()
else:
    productRanks = Product.query(Product.bidTime>=startDate
                                 Product.bidTime<endDate,
                                 Product.bidded=='no').fetch()
```

It looks really messy. Hypothetically, I'd like to be able to do the following. Is it possible? If yes, how?

```
condition = 'Product.bidTime>=startDate, Product.bidTime<endDate'
if bidded = 'yes':
    condition = condition + ', Product.bidded=='yes'
elif bidded == 'no':
    condition = condition + ', Product.bidded=='no'
productRanks = Product.query(condition).fetch()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really should spend some time reading the docs it will save you a lot of time.

See  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#filter_by_prop  If you read this section it clearly shows you can keep adding filters. From the docs the example is pretty clear.

```
qry1 = Account.query() # Retrieve all Account entitites
qry2 = qry1.filter(Account.userid >= 40) # Filter on userid >= 40
qry3 = qry2.filter(Account.userid < 50) # Filter on userid < 50 as well
```

And you don't have to keep creating a new query, just keep rebinding the same variable.

Comment: Thanks. But another problem is: When I performed filtering on different fields, I got the error message _"Only one inequality filter per query is supported. Encountered both ..."_

Comment: Thats correct. The error message reflects the limitations of the query capabilities of the datastore. You will probably need to change your model to aggeragate various values at write time to make the queries you want possible.

Comment: it may also pay to look at the search api and see what queries are possible there.

Comment: Well, I have to implement my own filtering function. Not too bad actually. But it looks odd -- query with ndb and then filter using my own code ;-)